# How to count great grandchild objects in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

can anyone help me count the number of great grandchild records in a Rails app?

For example, I want to do something like the following:

```
class Country
  has_many :states
  has_many :cities, :through => :states
  has_many :events, :through => :cities
end

class State
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :cities
  has_many :events, :through => :cities
end

class City
  has_one :country, :through => state
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :events
end

class Event
  belongs_to :city,  :counter_cache => true 
  has_one :state, :through => city,  :counter_cache => true 
  has_one :country, :through => :state, :counter_cache => true 
end
```

So I want to have access to the number of events for each city, for each state, and for each country.

I have City and State working, but don't seem to be able to get a counter_cache running on the great grandparent Country model.

Have I missed something? Is this possible? Is there a better way to do it?

I'd really appreciate some ideas from the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you watched the counter cache railscasts episode? It might be helpful.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column.

If you simply want to count several levels down, you can chain several statements to get your answer. However, this isn't going to be terribly efficient, because of the multiple DB calls to accomplish this, hence it would be better to cache the count, if you're going to be running this count often.

Here's an example of getting the count of all events in a country (untested), something like:

```
country = Country.find(params[:id])
number_of_events_in_country = 0
country.states.each{|s| s.cities.each{|c| number_of_events_in_country += c.events.count}}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion normalocity. I would prefer to cache the counter. Have you ever tried to count through long associations? I can't work out why my implementation is not working. Seems like it should....? Wondering if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Yeah, I've done counting through `has_many :through` association, though only to grandchildren (not great grandchildren) not several levels deep. However, I suppose that would look something like (in `app/models/country.rb`) `has_many :events, :through => :states`, and in `app/models/state.rb` an equivalent `has_many :events, :through => :cities`, and in `app/models/city.rb` an equivalent `has_many :events`. I think this sort of chaining might work.

Comment: The cache counter would be much simpler. So, when an `event` is created, it would do something like `event.city.update_attribute(:event_count_cache, event.city.event_count_cash + 1)`, followed by a similar count cache increment on `event.city.state` and so on, incrementing the counter at each level. You would, of course, need to make sure that if an event was destroyed, that the cache counter was updated in the reverse case, and if an event changed cities, that the cache counters were all decremented, than re-incremented with the new city/state, etc.

Comment: And of course you would want unit tests around the cache counter calculation, to cover cases of `event` adds, moves, and deletions. That way you could make sure that your counters didn't break at any point. Cached counters are awesome for efficiency, but if you don't wrap them in tests to make sure they maintain their integrity, you'll lose their value pretty quickly.

Comment: Oh, I apologize. So, what are we missing? From the code you posted in your question (now that I take another look at it) it seems like you should be able to do `country.events.count` and get the count back. That's not a cached count, but adding the count fields to each of the models, and having the code that creates, updates, and destroys `Event` records update the counters seems like it should work.

Comment: Hi normalocity, thanks for the help. I could of course create a custom method to increment/ decrement the counter on the grand parent model. What I was really looking for was any reason why the counter_cache method built into Rail wouldn't work in this situation. i.e. is this a limitation of the method, or should I spend more time trying to find an error in the way I've implemented it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, honestly I didn't realize that there was a `counter_cache` method built into Rails, so this was a case of me not realizing that was even an option. Have you tried using it in development? Does it break in a specific way?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a grandparent relationship you can just use `has_many` through (as you have listed above), but you have a great grandparent relationship and this doesn't work for that.

One thing you could do (if you have a multiple levels of parent child relationships) is put a method in your Country class to parse it out.

```
class Country
  has_many :states
  has_many :cities, :through => :states
  attr_accessor :events

  def initialize
    @events = Array.new
  end

  def get_events
    self.states.each{|s| s.each{|c| c.each{|e| @events << e }}}
  end

end
```

Then just call the get_events method and events will be populated with all the events associated to the first record.

```
usa = Country.first
usa.get_events
usa.events
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to figure this out. Just clicked on Jeff's answer's RailsCasts link and found this [6 yr old comment](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column?view=comments#comment_158362).

Basically, you can do what you want using the [counter_culture gem](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture#multi-level-counter-cache)'s multi-level caching features by passing it an array of the parents, walking back up to the top. Obviously, be sure to add the corresponding columns as normal.

```
class Event
  belongs_to :city
  has_one :state, :through => city
  has_one :country, :through => :state

  counter_culture [:city, :state, :country]
end
```